# Replace words in XML file

Tags: python, regex, xml, replace, xml-parsing

I need to write python script that will replace all occurences of certain words in xml file. I only need to replace banned words that are enclosed in tag.

This should be replaced:

```
<some_xml_tag>some text REPLACE_ME some text</some_xml_tag>
```

This should not:

```
<some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">some text</some_xml_tag>

<REPLACE_ME>some text</REPLACE_ME>
```

I am no regex expert but it should be possible or not?

Comment: Can this `REPLACE_ME` appear anywhere in the XML - in the tag name, text or attribute? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem. But will be replaced only if it is enclosed in the tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an *XML parser* instead.

Example using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) library. Here we are using `xpath()` to search for the nodes with the desired text and then replace it using `replace()`:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

ban_word = 'REPLACE_ME'
replacement = 'HELLO'

data = """<root>
    <some_xml_tag>REPLACE_ME</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">some text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>some text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

for item in root.xpath('//*[. = "%s"]' % ban_word):
    item.text = item.text.replace(ban_word, replacement)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Prints:

```
<root>
    <some_xml_tag>HELLO</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">some text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>some text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
```

Notes:

- the comparison is case-insensitive
- `xml.etree.ElementTree` would not handle this particular approach since it provides only *limited `xpath` support*
- as @tdelaney noted in comments, if you have a list of words to replace, it might be a good idea to simply iterate over all nodes and replace the text if necessary

Comment: Great answer but if there are many words you want to compare or if you want to do case insensitive compares, it may be better to iterate all of the elements and compare the text in python.

Comment: very nice approach +1

Comment: @tdelaney this is a valid point. There are many ifs/caveats here, let's wait for what the OP would respond. Thanks.

Comment: Replacing should be case sensitive

Comment: @zdarsky.peter okay, I'll be afk for a while. In case there would not be other options, I'll edit the answer and provide you with one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As an extension/alternative from @alexce's answer, bottom line is: you can still iterate all child elements and replace all words in loops:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

ban_words = ['REPLACE_ME', 'Some']
replacement = 'HELLO'

data = """<root>
    <some_xml_tag>REPLACE_me</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">Some text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>some text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(data)
# different approach using iter()
for node in root.iter():
    for word in ban_words:
        node.text = node.text.replace(word, replacement)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Results will be case sensitive as in your list, too:

```
<root>
    <some_xml_tag>REPLACE_me</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">HELLO text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>some text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
```

#### UPDATED

If you don't want connected words to be replaced, you can use a dictionary to match the banned words and replacement, something like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
ban = {'REPLACE_ME': 'HELLO', 'Some': 'HELLO'}

data = """<root>
    <some_xml_tag>REPLACE_me</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">REPLACE_ME Some text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>someSome Some SomeSOME text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(data)
# different approach using iter()
for node in root.iter():
    txt = node.text.split(" ")
    for i, t in enumerate(txt):
        if ban.get(t):
            txt[i] = ban.get(t)
    node.text = ' '.join(txt)

print ET.tostring(root)
```

Results which connected words won't be replaced, only EXACT matches will be:

```
<root>
    <some_xml_tag>REPLACE_me</some_xml_tag>
    <some_xml_tag attr="REPLACE_ME">HELLO HELLO text</some_xml_tag>
    <REPLACE_ME>someSome HELLO SomeSOME text</REPLACE_ME>
</root>
```

Comment: That is kinda what I have. I just included some more logic, so it will replace only exact match and not part of word containing banned word.

Comment: If it is okay with you, I will set post from @alecxe as accepted answer, because I really like the idea and other people that wants the same thing will hopefully read the whole thread

Comment: @zdarsky.peter, I also think alecxe's should be the accepted answer, provided that the key method is to do a pattern matching under a for loop, and there were some uncleared requirements

Comment: Thank you both! I'll definitely upvote as soon a new SO day would start.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for sure... but instead of using a regex, try ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

This will make it much easier to find/replace element text values as opposed to element attributes, etc.